# merge parshat-matot into mattos

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-tag, tag-synonyms

I just asked a question about this week's parsha and didn't see a match when I typed "matot" so I created [parshat-matot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshat-matot).  I then went to add it to the systematic list of tags and saw [mattos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mattos) there.  This is a request to create a synonym.  (I don't have enough rep in the tag to suggest it the usual way.)

Comment: Although this is well within scope for meta, I generally just leave a note in chat for simple requests like this, just to keep the meta stack a little cleaner.

Comment: @DoubleAA, oh, I didn't realize.  Should I delete this now that it's been dealt with?

Comment: I don't think that is necessary. Like I said, this is completely in scope. MSO has an entire tag dedicated to these kinds of requests http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request . I was just giving you a suggestion for the future. There is definitely not a policy my way, but if you dis/agree with the logic feel free to take it or leave it.

Comment: See also discussion in the comments here http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/780/759